# disable input on check checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, input

Need to disable an input when the check-box is unchecked, and when it is checked enable it.

My code is like this:

```
<div class="y">
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" />
    <input type="select" name="x" class="mySelect" />
</div>

<div class="y">
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" />
    <input type="select" name="x" class="mySelect" />
</div>

<div class="y">
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" />
    <input type="select" name="x" class="mySelect" />
</div>
```

But I want to disable and enable the select input which correspond to a check-box. If user clicks in first check box enable first input, and do the same for second and third.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One simple solution:

```js
$(".mySelect").prop("disabled", true);

$("input:checkbox").on("change", function () {
    $(this).next().prop("disabled", !$(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="y">
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" />
    <input type="select" name="x" class="mySelect" />
</div>
<div class="y">
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" />
    <input type="select" name="x" class="mySelect" />
</div>
<div class="y">
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" />
    <input type="select" name="x" class="mySelect" />
</div>
```

**References**

[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: OP wanted the inverse of this.. need to change to !$(this).prop("checked")

Comment: With `input.mySelect:disabled {
background: #eee;
}` you can dim the disabled input fields. Feel free to alter this CSS at your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the pure CSS route, you can write CSS that changes the `opacity` and `pointer-events` when the checkbox sibling is unchecked.

```css
.y .myCheck:not(:checked) + .mySelect {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="y">
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" />
    <input type="text" tabindex="-1" name="x" class="mySelect" />
</div>

<div class="y">
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" />
    <input type="text" tabindex="-1" name="x" class="mySelect" />
</div>

<div class="y">
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" />
    <input type="text" tabindex="-1" name="x" class="mySelect" />
</div>
```

**Tab Issue**

In order to stop someone from tabbing into the input, you can add `tabindex="-1"` to the input.